# Read an Excel file's columns and print its count using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, parsing

My requirement is to read 200 excel files in a folder and i want the column header count for each every excel file in that folder using Nodejs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you attempted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) is a package for your problem handle read excel (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx). Please take time to read document how it's working. It's a parser and writer for various spreadsheet formats.

You can also try this tutorial, simple how to use this package. [JavaScript – Reading Excel file using node.js! Solved!](https://thewebspark.com/2018/05/13/how-to-access-excel-sheets-data-using-node-js/)

Comment: Hey...Thanks alot its working now. But now i have another problem, my excel file is having null value but JSON is not capturing them ,Is there way to handle null values in JSON . Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is old library. Thank you for the recent validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('DummyExcel.xlsx');

var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]))
```

Use the above snippet